# Marker clustering default cluster appearing

Tags: java, android, google-maps

So basically i want to cluster custom markers like shown in doc. just without pictures https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering#maps_android_utils_clustering_info_window-java. I am having hard time understanding why is default marker appearing when map is zoomed

[image]
[image]

My CustomMarker class looks like this

```
    public class CustomMarker extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MapMarker> {
    private final IconGenerator iconGenerator;
    private final IconGenerator clusterIconGenerator;
    private final ImageView imageView;
    private final int markerWidth;
    private final int markerHeight;

    public CustomMarker(Context context,
                        GoogleMap map,
                        ClusterManager<MapMarker> clusterManager) {

        super(context, map, clusterManager);
        int padding = 0;
        markerWidth = 200;
        markerHeight = 200;
        clusterIconGenerator = new IconGenerator(getActivity());
        
        imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(markerWidth, markerHeight));
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

        iconGenerator = new IconGenerator(getActivity());
        iconGenerator.setContentView(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(@NonNull MapMarker item, @NonNull MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(item.getPicture()));
        Bitmap icon = iconGenerator.makeIcon();
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon)).title(item.getTitle());
        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);

    }



    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<MapMarker> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {

        markerOptions.visible(false);
        Bitmap icon = clusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()));
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
        markerOptions.visible(true);
 }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster cluster) {
        return cluster.getSize() > 2;
    }
}
```

And in the function in which i set marker i set the following
[image]

Thank you for any kind of help!

Comment: Where did you override `getDescriptorForCluster()`?

Answer (score 1):

Default cluster appeared because i did not override

```
 protected void onClusterUpdated(@NonNull Cluster<MapMarker> cluster, @NonNull com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker marker)
```

this method should be same as your `onBeforeClusterRendered`